# Unknown Facebook API Error 1383066

Tags: facebook, payment

I'm developing Facebook payment interface for my game. I did everything as described in documentation. And I came to the strange situation where "Asynchronous Payment Method" works just fine (I see callback calls to my server) but immediate "Test Payment Method" doesn't work (I do not see callback call to my server). Instead FB.ui call returns this error:

```
{
  error_code: 1383066,
  error_message: "Something went wrong while processing your payment…harged for this transaction, so please try again."
}
```

Here is a screenshot with error: http://monosnap.com/image/DetZ1VqEy1d7yuiVXdJLUZdL1Ukl45

Can anyone help?

p.s. I searched in Internet ant there is no information about FB API Error 1383066

Comment: This is an "unknown error" code. Have you set up your app to test this with correctly? Especially the domain settings? Also, are you referring to the correct app id in the Payment object? If you've checked this, and it still happens, you can file a bug report here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

Problem just gone by itself. I think that it was an issue on FB side and they just fixed it.